# Rebuild perl instmodsh command index

Tags: perl, centos5

```
Lang/Env:Perl 
Version: 5.8.8
OS: CentOS 5.3
```

How does instmodsh works exactly? **How it create indexes?** Is there any way to rebuild these indexes ? Is there any other tool available for managing modules ?

When I am using "instmodsh" for below module it is showing following output:
    XML::NamespaceSupport
    XML::XML::NamespaceSupport

Why is so ? It is installed only once and single version only.
Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another part of the question "Is there any other tool available for managing modules ?"
One tool is available:

```
perlmod
```

It  provides features like installation of modules, remove, print version, files of a modules etc.

You can get this tool at 
http://www.seofreetools.net/download/scripts/perlmod/perlmod.v.1.1.0.tar.gz

and rest of the information.